# Is there a way to search/filter gmail emails by the absolute domain without subdomains (e.g. google.com, but not plus.google.com)

Tags: gmail, gmail-filters, gmail-search

Is there a way to search/filter gmail emails by the absolute domain without subdomains? If just do a search/filter on `from:@google.com` it includes all subdomains like `plus.google.com`, `txt.voice.google.com`, etc.

I know I can manually exclude all of those with `-{from:plus.google.com from:txt.voice.google.com}`, but the list of subdomains is quite long (and I don't really know the full list).

Comment: Did you try from:"@google.com" ?

Comment: Yes, ```from:"@google.com"``` unfortunately works the same as ```from:@google.com```. It really seems like gmail is ignoring the ```@``` sign.

Answer (score 3):

What you can use is a Google Script that does regex match with the TO field to find emails with an exact domain in the address:

```
function myFunction() {

  var label = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName("Google.com");
  if (!label) label = GmailApp.createLabel("Google.com");

  var threads = GmailApp.search("from:google.com");
  for (var t in threads) {
    var msg = threads[t].getMessages()[0];
    if (msg.getTo().match(/\@google\.com/)) {
      threads[t].addLabel(label);
    }
  }

}
```

Also see: [Advanced Gmail Search with RegEx](http://www.labnol.org/internet/advanced-gmail-search/21623/)

Comment: I like the idea, and it eliminated ```txt.voice.google.com```, but for some reason I still see ```plus.google.com```. I've looked at the original message and it sures looks to me like your trick should work. The From line is ```From: "Google+" <noreply-2xxxxxxb@plus.google.com>```

Comment: PS, Thanks for your blog. It's helped me out in the past :).

Comment: Actually, it doesn't seem to be working me at all now. It seems like the search engine ignores the periods.

Comment: Unfortunately, I does not work. I've started a bounty, hoping for answers...

Comment: See my updated answer.