# Gmail search using exact search string

Tags: gmail, gmail-search

Doing a search via regular Gmail frontend in the browser, shows strange results.

I want to search all mails from

```
*@ebay.*
```

My search:

```
from:@ebay
```

shows also emails sent from an ebay subdomain:

```
eBay@reply.ebay.com
```

It seems like Gmail ignores the "@", otherwise I can't see why those messages appear in the search results.

I also tried following searches with no success:

```
from:"@ebay"
from:'@ebay'
from:(@ebay)
from:("@ebay")
from:('@ebay')
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
from:ebay.* -from:members.ebay.de
```

Basically you're telling it to search on emails from ebay.* but NOT from that subdomain on that domain.

Answer (score 0):

As you correctly stated: ...shows also emails sent from an ebay subddomain - the search is in fact doing exactly the right thing by including all subdomains of your search term. To remedy this you can choose to filter out known keywords by doing the following:

from:*@amazon.de

You don't actually need the @ symbol for this. More on [Wildcard Characters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wildcard_character) like the * symbol.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I know wildcards and I tried them. But Gmail does not support wildcards in the way we usually know them...

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand what you're looking for here because **@ebay** is not an email address.
If you wish to see emails received from a particular email address, use:

```
from: email@domain.com
```

for instance, if you were searching for emails sent by Ebay, you'd probably search for:

```
from: *@ebay.*
```

OR

```
from: *@*.ebay.*
```

that should bring up all the emails you received from ebay.com, ebay.in, reply.ebay.com, etc

Comment: Oh, unfortunately the stars in my original post got lost! Actually I want to search for all emails from an ebay top level domain without the subdomains. That's exactly the difference between your two suggestions. But when I use your first suggestion, gmail still shows the subdomains mails like foobar@members.ebay.de

Comment: I think [this](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/40841/is-there-a-way-to-search-filter-gmail-emails-by-the-absolute-domain-without-subd) is what you're looking for. However it didn't seem to exclude certain emails